# getting inverted image while converting layout to bitmap in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to convert my layout to image using the code below.

```
LinearLayout rlpage = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlpage);
rlpage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap viewBitmap = rlpage.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
viewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
 byte[] toSend = baos.toByteArray();  
        try {
            fileOutputStream.write(toSend);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

this is the my layout

[image]

this is the output image

[image]

what is the reason for this and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
image_view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bmp =Bitmap.createBitmap(image_view.getDrawingCache());
            image_view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
```

You can replace your image_view with your particular layout.

Comment: already used png,and the result is same.is there any advantage of using `image_view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);`

Comment: No it will just close your DrawingCache for a layout.As we use setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); it allows to get image.Same as we are using to close the Drawingcache as per my knowledge.And be specific at this line Bitmap bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(image_view.getDrawingCache());

Comment: when i use png format,it will give an image with transparent area which is the replacement for the black area.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason is that JPEG only supports fully opaque pixels. As Meghs suggested it would be better to use compression to PNG. Take look at [compress() method documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).